# What does these terms mean?

Tags: genomics, wgs, copy-number

I am working on cancer genomics failed to follow some terms even by googling

What is the difference of ***focal genome amplifications*** versus ***convergent amplification*** of given region of genome for instance fibroblast growth factors region?

Thank you for any clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think these definitions still have a degree of subjectivity and I don't think they are mutually exclusive.

Convergent amplification basically means that "similar" cancers/neoplasms have "similar" amplification patterns, i.e. at around the same loci (see [Myllykangas S et al.,2006](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/16751803) for an example).

Focal genome amplification is defined as "CNA [copy number alteration] of limited size, frequently enriched for cancer driver genes" ([Krijgsmanthis et al., 2014](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167488914003000?via%3Dihub)).